# Upload photo/file to server PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am unable to successfully upload an image/file to my server. The php is as follows:

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved
$uploadDir = "./";
$uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)){
    echo "The file has been uploaded successfully.";
} else {
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

I chose the directory at which this script lives, to ensure the functionality before I upload to the final directory. I want to upload photo's, and will check for file extensions later - but for now I at least need the upload functionality to work.

I get an empty array returned.

** EDIT ** 
Also, `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is enabled on the form, and I am submitting it via AJAX.

The form is as follows:

```
<form id="imageUploadForm" name="imageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="photo" class="blogLabel">Upload an Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="imageUpload" onChange="uploadImage();">
</form>
```

I do realize that I shouldn't use "onChange" to submit the form.

The AJAX to submit the form is as follows:

```
function uploadImage() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url:'imageController.php', 
        data:$('#imageUploadForm').serialize(),
        success: function(responseSubmit) {
                alert(responseSubmit);
            }
     });
};
```

Comment: common error is to leave "enctype="multipart/form-data"" off the form. http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: That is indeed enabled - Sorry, should have made a note of that. I will edit the question to include that.

Comment: post the whole form, if $_FILES is empty that's where the problem will be

Comment: Can you show what your form looks like?

Comment: What you are doing right now is very dangerous.  Do not put files within your web root.  Do not leave files named the same as what the user specified.  Pick a random name, or something the hash of the file, with no file extension.  You don't want someone uploading something_evil.php and remotely controlling your server with it!  You can recover the original file names later when you serve up those files via a script.

Comment: you cant do a file upload via ajax. iframe is the only option with out a page refresh.

Comment: The files won't be uploaded to the actual web root - I just need to confirm the functionality... at which point I will secure it all.

Comment: No file upload via AJAX eh? Fair enough - I was not aware of that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: @mdance DONT CHANGE YOUR WHOLE QUESTION. MAKE A NEW QUESTION PLEASE. I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 4):

You **cannot** upload a file via ajax like that.

This will result in **no file being uploaded at all**!

You can only do a regular form submit to submit a file to the server in the way you want to do it.

---

As shown in the comments -- you can do a hidden iframe trick to submit the files to the server **without using ajax**.

---

**Or**
[you can use XHR2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/)

Comment: @Dagon haha I just loaded that comment :-P Great minds think alike ^_^

Comment: Yes, Thank you :) I was not aware of that.

Comment: @Dagon we were about 15 seconds apart in our posting :-P

Comment: still can do the iframe "trick" will result in no full page reload - if that is what the op wanted

Comment: @Dagon true. I added that to the answer.

Comment: I removed the AJAX, and am submitting "normally" and get the same result. Could it be permissions?

Comment: @mdance you should open this in a new question.

Comment: I will open it in a new question.